# Replacing an old textfile with a new textfile in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I was just wondering how I would go about replacing a certain bit of a text in a textfile in Java?

For example if I had a text file with the following contents:

```
John: My Status is: 0;
William: My Status is: 0;
Andrew: My Status is: 1;
Bob: My Status is: 1;
Smith: My Status is: 0;
```

And I wanted to replace the line containing the string "William" with `"William: My Status is: 1;"`

So, the new textfile should look like this:

```
John: My Status is: 0;
William: My Status is: 1;
Andrew: My Status is: 1;
Bob: My Status is: 1;
Smith: My Status is: 0;
```

I am still relatively new to OOP so some help would really be appreciated! This is how I've done it thus far:

1. Read through the file line by line. Write and Append each line to a new temporary text file.
2. If the line contains the word "William", then replace the line with "William: My status is: 1" and then append to the temporary text file.
3. Replace my old textfile with the temporary text file

Now the bit I'm stuck at is step 3! (The step I thought would be the easiest!).

It seems the content gets written correctly to the temporary textfile, but for some reason I can't get it to replace the old textfile! This is my actual code so far: (Sorry if its too much to read, if it is then if you could just give me some general advice that would be great too!)

```
public void verifyUser(UserDataObject u) {

    String eachline = "";
    String uname = u.getUsername();
    Scanner sc;
    try {
        File file1 = new File("FlatFileStorage.txt");
        sc = new Scanner(file1);

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("TempFlatFileStorage.txt", true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            eachline = sc.nextLine();

            if ( eachline.contains(uname) ) {
                int lineStart = eachline.indexOf("Username: " + uname);
                int lineEnd = eachline.indexOf("end" + uname + ";");
                int unameLength = uname.length();

                String lineStatus = eachline.substring(lineStart, lineEnd + 4 + unameLength);
                //System.out.println(lineStatus);

                String newLineStatus = lineStatus.replace("VerifyStatus: 0", "VerifyStatus: 1");
                System.out.println(newLineStatus);
                out.println(newLineStatus);

            } else {
            System.out.println(eachline);
            out.println(eachline); }
        }

        out.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: Could not find database/storage."); } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There has been an error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
    }


File file = new File("FlatFileStorage.txt");
File tempfile = new File("TempFlatFileStorage.txt");
tempfile.renameTo(file);
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you delete the old file first?

Comment: Problem! I was an idiot, it never fixed it. Cannot seem to fix this problem no matter what... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating **temp file** You can use this code.
Here instead of creating temp file.
I added file content to `StringBuilder` object and after iteration completes,
printed that `StringBuilder` object to the same file.So that you do not need to create
temp file here and rename it to old one or delete old file.Please look into my code.

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("filepath")));
    String line = null;
    StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = br.readLine())!=null) 
    {
        if(line.indexOf(uname)!=-1)
        {
            //do your logic here
            sb.append("your logic here"+"\n");
        }else{
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
    } 
    br.close();
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("filepath")));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);
    out.print(sb.toString());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I was just wondering how I would go about replacing a certain bit of a text in a textfile in Java?
```

This problem is like the random file access. It is difficult to do if you did not delete the original file and make a new one. Probably **search** the string first and the **replace** in the memory and **overwrite** the file.

### What to do?

Use the XML file instead. There is an easy and efficient method **XMLparsing**. You can find the complete ready made different **examples** [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/). It is very helpful, *instead of saving the record type text in Simple Text file.*

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have no other problem with the *logic* (i.e. what you want to achieve through this) as I have noticed from the examples you gave, the following lines:

```
int lineStart = eachline.indexOf("Username: " + uname); 
int lineEnd = eachline.indexOf("end" + uname + ";"); 
int unameLength = uname.length();
```

return -1 to `lineStart` and `lineEnd`

To solve your current problem add `sc.close();` & `file1.delete();`

```
//
//
//Modified Lines
  sc.close();
  out.close();
  file1.delete();             

 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("Error: Could not find database/storage.");
}
//Catch Statement and remaining Code
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply. I did that though and it still didn't work. Turns out its a pretty old bug (one of the very few) in Java.

I had to call the garbage collector and do the whole file replacing thing in another method/class. But it worked :)